# .Net core Fluent validation accept empty or accept with given precision

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

Hi I am trying to validate one decimal field in .Net core using fluent validation. The field can be empty or if the values present then it should match precision 4,1. I have tried so far

```
this.RuleFor(x => x.MastHeight).NotNull().ScalePrecision(1, 4).When( x => x.MastHeight).NotEmpty();
```

The above code is not correct. The validations I am trying to implement below rules

> 1. Mast height cannot be null
> 2. Mast height may take empty
> 3. Mast height can take zero
> 4. If values present in mast height then it should follow precision 1,4

Can someone help me to write correct validation with including above rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean Empty in decimal properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    RuleFor(p => p.MastHeight)
        .ScalePrecision(1, 4)
        .When(p => p.MastHeight != decimal.Zero && p.MastHeight.HasValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer so when I send empty value to mast height will it work?

Comment: Can you explain what is Empty Value ?  default(decimal ) ?

Comment: When user sends model like MastHeight :     (Actually here nothing)

Comment: Decimal cannot accept empty values . If your decimal is nullable and user don't send any value then the default value is set to null.

Comment: yeah my decimal field is nullable, user may not send any value

Comment: So you should remove NotNull() validation and Add p.MastHeight != null in your second validation When

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `.When( x => x.MastHeight).NotEmpty()` -it won't even compile-.

[`ScalePrecision(1,4)`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#scaleprecision-validator) means you allow for 4 digits in total, and 1 decimal place, so it will accept the zero (empty decimal) without the need for a special rule.

```cs
public class MyType {
    public decimal? MastHeight { get; set; }
    public MyType(decimal? mastHeight) {
        MastHeight = mastHeight;
    }
}

public class MyTypeValidator : AbstractValidator<MyType> {
    public MyTypeValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.MastHeight).NotNull().ScalePrecision(1, 4);
    }
}

[Fact]
public void Decimal_Validation_Valid() {
    var decimals = new MyType[] {
        new MyType(default(decimal)),
        new MyType(1m),
        new MyType(1234m),
        new MyType(1.4m),
        new MyType(321.4m),
    };

    var validator = new MyTypeValidator();

    foreach (var value in decimals) {
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(value);
        Assert.True(validationResult.IsValid);
    }
}

[Fact]
public void Decimal_Validation_Invalid() {
    var decimals = new MyType[] {
        new MyType(null),
        new MyType(1.42m),
        new MyType(1111.4m),
    };

    var validator = new MyTypeValidator();

    foreach (var value in decimals) {
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(value);
        Assert.False(validationResult.IsValid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer so when I send empty value to mast height will it work?

Comment: @Niranjangodbole You can't have an 'empty' decimal. If the field is defined as a nullable decimal i.e. `decimal?` (as I did in the example), then its default value is set to null. If it is defined as value type `decimal` then its default value is set to `0`. In other words, you can't have 'empty', it's either null or zero, and both will be handled fine by the rule (null is invalid, while zero is valid).

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know the actual concept. So user cannot send empty to decimal field so he should send either zero or null right? for example, when user sends in model like MastHeight :   (actually here nothing)

Comment: @Niranjangodbole They can send an empty object of `MyType` i.e. `var obj = new MyType()`. The fields on the object will be initialized to their default values. Since `MastHeight` is defined as `decimal?`, it will have a default value of `null`, and it will be treated as invalid, and return a validation error.